# How to create a Gdk.Pixbuf from uint8[]

Tags: gtk, vala, gdk

I have a `uint8[]` (that I got from a [`Gst.MapInfo.data`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gstreamer-1.0/Gst.MapInfo)) that represents an image (I don't know which format JPEG, PNG, etc) and **I want to get a `Gdk.Pixbuf` out of it**.

The issue is that [the only `PixBuf` constructor](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gdk-pixbuf-2.0/Gdk.Pixbuf.Pixbuf.from_data) that would take a `uint8[]` also requires a lot of other image info that I don't have: colorspace, size, etc.

> Note I can't use a PixBufLoader because I want my image created synchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your `uint8[]` in a [`GLib.MemoryInputStream`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gio-2.0/GLib.MemoryInputStream) and using [`new Pixbuf.from_stream()`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gdk-pixbuf-2.0/Gdk.Pixbuf.Pixbuf.from_stream).